# Does the mse loss equal the L2 loss in an autoencoder?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I have been trying to implement an variational autoencoder on a texture dataset. For that I used the VAE example given by Keras as a base and changed the layers to my liking. Since the example uses binary crossentropy loss I wanted to change it to the L2 loss because a Paper regarding a texture autoencoder suggested so.

I have searched how to implement the L2 loss, but did not quite find a clear answer. Is the mse loss equal to the L2 loss in the context of the variational autoencoder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $L_2$ loss *is* another name for squared error. Not in autoencoders, but in general. $L_2$ in the name comes from [the norm in mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)). In different places you would see either sum of squared errors, or their mean, but they are technically equivalent, while mean is preferred since it has units independent of sample size.